# Pass HTML code trough Ajax Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying pass a html code trough Ajax like this:

Using plugin 'summernote' (WYSIWYG Editor)

```
var description = $('#ticketDescription').code();
```

This give me for example:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;">asdasdasd<span>sadasd
```

and when Ajax process this give an 500 internal error

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/Ticket/NewTicket',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    companyId: companyId,
                    subject: subject,
                    ticketDescription: description
                },

                success: function(result) {
                    ....
                },
                error: function(result) {

                }
            });
```

The problem is solved by removing the '<' character from string.
Any solution to this?
Thanks

Edit: The only way I found so far is:
In javascript:

```
description = escape(description);
```

and in the controller:

```
ticketDescription = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ticketDescription);
```

Is it correct?

Comment: You need to find the underlying reason for the 500 error code that's coming from the server.

Comment: The reason is the '<' character in the string... ex: <span>

Comment: Yes, I read that in your question. That doesn't change the fact that you need to find the underlying reason for the 500 error code. Find out *why* the server is choking on the `<` and then deal it. Check your error logs on the server side.

Comment: And how I find that reason? PS: Edited the post

Comment: You have found one workaround, but it may not be the most elegant. If I were you, I would look in the error logs and see what the exception was. If you don't know how to look in the error logs, drop everything and focus on that, because you need to set up logging in your application! [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is a good place to get started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ValidateInput** and **AllowHtml** attribute is what you need to set in the property

By default Asp.Net MVC doesn't allow a user to submit html for avoiding Cross Site Scripting attack to your application.

**ValidateInput Attribute**

This is the simple way to allow the submission of HTML. This attribute can enable or disable input validation at the controller level or at any action method.
ValidateInput at Controller Level

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
 public ActionResult AddArticle()
 {
 return View();
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddArticle(BlogModel blog)
 {
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {

 }
 return View();
 }
}
```

Now, the user can submit Html for this Controller successfully.
ValidateInput at Action Method Level

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
 public ActionResult AddArticle()
 {
 return View();
 }

 [ValidateInput(false)]
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddArticle(BlogModel blog)
 {
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {

 }
 return View();
 }
}
```

Now, the user can submit Html for this action method successfully.

Limitation of ValidateInput attribute
This attribute also has the issue since this allow the Html input for all the properties and that is unsafe. Since you have enable Html input for only one-two properties then how to do this. To allow Html input for a single property, you should use AllowHtml attribute.

**AllowHtml Attribute**

This is the best way to allow the submission of HTML for a particular property. This attribute will be added to the property of a model to bypass input validation for that property only. This explicit declaration is more secure than the ValidateInput attribute.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class BlogModel
{
 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "Title")]
 public string Title { get; set; }

 [AllowHtml]
 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "Description")]
 public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

Make sure, you have removed the ValidateInput attribute from Conroller or Action method. Now, the user can submit Html only for the Description property successfully.

Comment: ^ and to display html in the view use: @Html.Raw("<html></html>"); This was the only thing missing in your answer.

Comment: That's is was I looking for. Thanks... Just put [ValidateInput(false)] in the Method and works. Edit: Im not using Model...