# ValidateInput(bool) in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Framework when I want to pass HTML code from Javascript to Controller just wrote [ValidateInput(false)] before Method and no problem for me:

Just like my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633815/pass-html-code-trough-ajax-asp-net-mvc)

I need to know same but ASP.NET Core.

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ValidateInput' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks

Comment: According to [this thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/324), there is no request validation in core at all, you are supposed to do it yourself instead

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In asp.net core you may not need to add this attribute, because, by default, the validation is not so strict as in ASP.NET MVC 4 or 5.

For example, passing HTML code via POST to a controller does throw an exception in older versions of ASP.NET(eg MVC 5)

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client

whereas in ASP.NET core, there is no exception.